# Guest account to Root account

Tags: login, password, users, guest-session

I have a Dell with Ubuntu 14.04, with no root account enabled, only guest (in the terminal). There is no account and no passwd.

I can't create a passwd. I can't unlock guest or root account. `sudo` command doesn't work. Ubuntu tells me that anything I do will be erased on log out.

Comment: If the question is 'how do I obtain root?' the answer is to ask the owner (or admin) of the system for a login account with appropriate permission. If you are the (new?) owner of the machine, then wipe the disk and do a  fresh install of Ubuntu.

Comment: tanks man, the notebook dosen't came with cd, i will try the store...

Comment: If you are indeed using the "guest" account root / sudo access is going to be blocked by apparmor

Comment: sudo dosen't work.  APPARMOR?  can i unbloked using this?

Comment: @MarceloFlores you can download any Ubuntu flavor you want and create live media from any OS. No need to go to the store.

Answer (score 1):

If you are NOT the owner of the machine, then ask the owner (or admin) for a login account with appropriate permission.

If you ARE the owner of the machine, consider wiping the disk and doing a complete fresh install of Ubuntu. You don't know how the previous owner configured the system...and what backdoors they may have left behind.

Well, that's not quite true - you DO know that their login account and full admin permissions still work! All your data is already open to them anytime they wish.